# ECL37130: Invalid host session specified. (IBM AS400 PCOMM)

Tags: vbscript, macros, ibm-midrange

I have an issue with running macros via the AS400 Emulator that just started today. I was running macros just fine earlier and then all of the sudden I kept receiving the below error. It appears that the first line of code is bugging out all of a sudden, this line is:

```
autECLSession.SetConnectionByName(ThisSessionName)
```

Here is the complete header code.

```
[PCOMM SCRIPT HEADER]
LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT
DESCRIPTION=
[PCOMM SCRIPT SOURCE]
OPTION EXPLICIT
autECLSession.SetConnectionByName(ThisSessionName)
```

I am utilizing VBScript and the PCOMM script source in my macro.

This happening for all of my macros across the board. I have no clue what I did that created this error.

I have already tried restarting my CPU (shutting down), reverting back to a previous version of the Emulator and IBM folder.

I installed a few macros on a co workers cpu and it worked just fine. I tried running a macro that is not utilizing VBscript and is instead using the "Macro file" option when recording the macro and it is working perfectly.

I am not sure where to go here but any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

[errormessageone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK08k.jpg)

[errormessagetwo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqWbd.jpg)

Comment: First look for something in the profile used for connection.  Like the network neighborhood bits.

Comment: Where would I look for this? I have System I navigator and I do not have command line access. I am using the AS400 emulator to run the macros.

Comment: IDK for navigator.  It shows in the qhst log when profiles are disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this problem, I had to rebuild (delete AS400 sessions and then create new sessions) my AS400 sessions via the "IBM Personal Communications - Sessions Manager". You can access the IBM sessions manager using the "Start or Configure Session" shortcut option found in the IBM System i Access for Windows/Emulator folder found in the start menu.

Answer (score 0):

According to the help:

> autECLSession - SetConnectionByName Method: void
>   SetConnectionByName(BSTR SessName)
>
> Sets the session object using the session name. In PCOMM this session
>   name is the short session ID (characters A-Z). There can be only one
>   PCOMM session open with a given name. For example, there can be only
>   one session "A" open at a time.
>
> Input Parameters:  BSTR SessName One character string short name of
>   the session (A-Z)

So `autECLSession.SetConnectionByName(ThisSessionName)` doesn't appear to be valid.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I never had an issue with this line before, it is automatically added even when I record a VBScript macro via the AS400 emulator. I have even ran the macro(s) as is on other peoples cpu and it worked fine. This only started happening yesterday afternoon (it worked earlier that morning). I tried changing the session name such as "A" but it still did not work, I also tried the other sessions as well.